# cross-compile with research ISA

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to cross-compiling ROS2 onto a research platform with a new ABI and an extension to the RISC-V ISA.  I need some help either manually building or making use of the existing cross-compile tools.

My test applications are fairly simple, and I was able to cross-compile ROS[1] applications manually (i.e., avoiding catkin) by converting them to rosserial applications.  I eventually built an entire TurtleBot3 for my research platform this way (including teleop).

Now I'm looking to ROS2 for some of its real-time possibilities.

My normal cross-compile invocation for a rosserial application is something like this:

```
$HOME/cheri/output/sdk/bin/cheri-unknown-freebsd-clang++ \
        $SRC1 $SRC2 -o $BIN \
        -g \
        -I$HOME/ros_lib \
        -mabi=purecap \
        --sysroot=$HOME/cheri/output/sdk/sysroot128 \
```

I'm not sure I can get this to translate to the docker/QEMU-based cross-compile tool (https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile).

Is there a simpler way for me to use `colcon` or a recommendation for calling `cmake` directly?

I'm only trying to build a simple talker/listener demo at this point, so we're talking one package, two source files, and one message type.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348210/cross-compile-with-research-isa/) by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2020-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-02**:
Cross-compilation with CMake essentially comes down to providing it a suitable [toolchain](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) file. Is that something you already have for your toolchain?

I'm not claiming this will solve everything (especially sysroot stuff can be tricky to get right), but it would be a big step towards cross-compiling "arbitrary" projects which based their build scripts on CMake.

**Comment by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on 2020-04-02**:
Yes, I have a CMake toolchain file.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-02**:
Seeing as `ros-tooling/cross_compile` is just about the most convenient way to cross-compile an entire ROS workspace without jumping through all sorts of hoops manually, it may pay off to post an issue on its [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile/issues). [ros-tooling/cross_compile#69](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile/issues/69) seems like it would be going in the direction of what you'd need.

**Comment by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on 2020-04-03**:
I'll follow your advice and post there, but I've also been playing with using my toolchain file with some success, but it chokes on finding PythonLibs.

Based on an invocation such as:

```
colcon build --ament-cmake-args -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/broomstick/ros2_cmake_test/CrossToolchain.cmake
```

I get errors like the following:

```
Starting >>> rcutils
--- stderr: rcutils                                                                                                            
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
  (Required is at least version "3.5")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
...
  CMakeLists.txt:120 (ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies)
```

**Comment by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on 2020-04-03**:
My toolchain file doesn't specify a location for Python and I assumed it would default to my system version.  This is probably dumb, but I'm not sure why.

**Comment by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on 2020-04-03**:
[update] I've added this to the `ros-tooling/cross_compile` [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile/issues/179).

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-04-06**:
Regarding the "PythonLibs not found issue", I've been facing the same with a native build and I believe this is due to rosdep behavior https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/752

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To close this question out:

It's challenging, as @gvdhoorn states, but I'm making progress using a cmake toolchain file.  You can find my current toolchain file [here](https://gist.github.com/dodsonmg/b19442c8aa2a4eebe7e970a4768fe4d7).

My toolchain file doesn't (currently) set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, so I pass that to cmake explicitly, as discussed [here](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile/issues/181).

I was able to fix (or bypass...) my PythonLibs problems by passing `-DBUILD_TESTING=NO`, as discussed [here](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile/issues/179).  This is not ideal, but is getting me over this immediate hurdle.

I also needed to pass `-DTHIRDPARTY=ON` to ensure my cross-compiled asio libraries are found.

Overall, my colcon invocation looks something like this:

```
colcon build \
    --cmake-args \
        -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$HOME/ws/CrossToolchain.cmake \
        -DBUILD_TESTING=NO \
        -DTHIRDPARTY=ON \
        -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$SYSROOT/usr/local/cheri;$SYSROOT/usr/local/cheri/libcheri/cmake \
    --no-warn-unused-cli
```

My problems at this point all appear to be related to cross-compile incompatibility problems (normal stuff) rather than problems specific to colcon or ROS, so I'm content.

---

Originally posted by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) with karma: 111 on 2020-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-08**:
Nice. Thanks for posting your approach here.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-08**:
Looks like it's [this architecture](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/ctsrd/cheri/), correct?

From your toolchain file, it appears your OS is FreeBSD(-based). Is that correct? Are there already any papers or other publications available detailing your work?

Did you have to patch anything in ROS 2 significantly to get it to build?

**Comment by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on 2020-04-10**:
Yes, that's correct.  There is a CHERI-aware version of FreeBSD, called CheriBSD.

No publications yet for the ROS-based CHERI work.  This is really our first foray into the cyber-physical domain.  ROS seemed like a good target, as it's open-source, lives in a fairly homogeneous ecosystem, and is well supported (including ROS Answers!).

As a proof of concept, I squashed the TurtleBot3 RPI and OpenCR code into a single rosserial-based executable and cross-compiled that successfully.  CHERI simplifies compartmentalisation, so I used it to split the network-facing communications functions from the physical control functions.  CHERI also lets you create certificate-like access tokens, so I was able to use that to control access to the `cmd_vel` topic.

The proof-of-concept worked well enough to start a more comprehensive port of ROS2.  I want to make use of some of it's potential in real-time systems targeting our CHERI-aware FreeRTOS and RTEMS.

**Comment by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on 2020-04-10**:
I'm only using a subset of ROS2 libraries at the moment, using [this repo](https://github.com/emersonknapp/ros2-toolchain-crosscompile) as a starting point (based on your earlier recommendation to talk to the `ros-tooling/cross_compile` folks.)

The required patches have been minimal.

**Comment by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on 2020-04-10**:
We have had to make some changes to SQLite to fix pointer alignment issues, so anything using `sqlite3.c` needs a patch.  This will eventually get upstreamed.

`poco` also selects some functions using preprocessor directives that check the size of longs and pointers.  CHERI confuses these conditionals because a capability/pointer is 128-bits in memory, though its still representing a 64-bit pointer.  This required a small patch.  I'm looking for a way to 'improve' the code so the maintainers are willing to accept a PR.

`rcutils` needed `__FreeBSD__` added to nearly every preprocessor directive that already included `__APPLE__`.  I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/pull/223), which was merged.

`rmw_cyclonedds` has an `align_` function that had some crazy casting and didn't work with our capabilities.  We cleaned the functions up a bit and submitted a [PR](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_cyclonedds/pull/141), which is approved and waiting merge.

**Comment by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on 2020-10-22**:
To follow up on an earlier question from gvdhoorn, our first [publication](https://conferences.computer.org/eurosp/pdfs/EuroSPW2020-7k9FlVRX4z43j4uE2SeXU0/859700a687/859700a687.pdf) involving CHERI and ROS is now public.